# Why is UTF-8 encoded the way it is?

Tags: utf-8

If I understood correctly, UTF-8 uses the following pattern to let the computer know how many bytes are going to be used to encode a character:

| Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0xxxxxxx |  |  |  |
| 110xxxxx | 10xxxxxx |  |  |
| 1110xxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |  |
| 11110xxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |

Etc. But aren't there more compact patterns? For instance, what is stopping us from using something like this:

| Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0xxxxxxx |  |  |  |
| 10xxxxxx | xxxxxxxx |  |  |
| 110xxxxx | xxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx |  |
| 1110xxxx | xxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx |

Comment: While your question may be interesting, it is not really on topic for SO: _"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."_ See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proposed encoding wouldn't be [self-synchronizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-synchronizing_code). If you landed in the middle of a stream on an `xxxxxxxx` byte, you'd have no idea whether it's in the middle of a character or not. If that random byte happened to be `10xxxxxx`, you could mistake it for the start of a character. The only way to avoid this mistake is to read the entire stream error free from the beginning.

It's an explicit goal for UTF-8 to be self-synchronizing. If you land anywhere in a UTF-8 stream, you *know* whether you're in the middle of a character or not, and need to read at most 3 bytes to find the next start of a full character.